# How to use a latest package version in a Yocto -older version?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using the following Yocto version,

```
DISTRO = "poky"
DISTRO_NAME = "Poky 8.0.1 (Yocto Project 1.3.1 Reference Distro)"
DISTRO_VERSION = "1.3.1"
SDK_VENDOR = "-pokysdk"
```

I want to upgrade the following packages.

1. Currently using package apt_0.7.14 and nee to upgrade to the latest version (say apt_1.2.12).
2. Currently using package eglibc-2.16 and nee to upgrade to the latest version. I think latest Yocto versions using glibc instead of eglibc.

I tried the following steps,

1. Copied the apt recipes Yocto-2.3\poky-pyro-17.0.0\meta\recipes-devtools/apt to my work space.
2. Initiated bitbake.
3. But I am getting some do_configure error given below,

> ```
> > checking for strings.h... (cached) yes checking for inttypes.h...
> > (cached) yes checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes checking for
> > unistd.h... (cached) yes checking db.h usability... yes checking db.h
> > presence... yes checking for db.h... yes checking if we can link
> > against BerkeleyDB... yes checking for curl_easy_init in -lcurl... no
> > configure: error: failed: I need CURL due https support Configure
> > failed. The contents of all config.log files follows to aid debugging
> > /home/ebike/work/STREAMS/Int_275/main/Yocto_Git/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/apt-1.2.12-r0/apt-1.2.12/config.log
> > This file contains any messages produced by compilers while running
> > configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.
> > 
> > It was created by configure, which was generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.
> > Invocation command line was
> > 
> >   $
> > /home/ebike/work/STREAMS/Int_275/main/Yocto_Git/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/apt-1.2.12-r0/apt-1.2.12/configure
> > --build=i686-linux --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr --exec_prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --sharedstatedir=/com --localstatedir=/var --libdir=/usr/lib --includedir=/usr/include --oldincludedir=/usr/include --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/ebike/work/STREAMS/Int_275/main/Yocto_Git/build/tmp/sysroots/imx6qsabrelite
> > --enable-nls ac_cv_lib_lzma_lzma_easy_encoder=yes ac_cv_lib_bz2_BZ2_bzopen=no
> > ac_cv_lib_lz4_LZ4F_createCompressionContext=no
> ```

It will be much appreciated, if anyone can help to solve this issue.

Comment: Getting some "do_configure" error isnt too helpful. Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: New version doesn't just include new file, you need to rename it, and go through step by step as you'd compile it on your machine. Be sure the SRC_URI, PV are set correctly, then you need to read step by step the errors. Probably compilation way changed between those 2 versions. Not much we can do here, I advise you to read current recipe for some packages, read older ones to see how it works

Comment: What is the reason for you to still using 1.3?  Is it because of the kernel or u-boot? upgrading packages will ensure that you have more bugs fixed and enhanced security.

Answer (score -1):

The trouble is that versions have a ripple effect in the system. The error you're seeing here likely amounts to "apt needs a newer version of curl than the one you have available". You could try upgrading curl as well however this kind of thing has a tendency to escalate. You will likely find software than needs newer gcc or kernel versions too.

Comment: A much more helpful answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60208833/1979048

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090283/1979048

Comment: The other answer points at how to find recipes. This question is about why this specific case fails and it is failing due to curl either not being a dependency in which case a new DEPENDS is needed, or curl is an incorrect (likely too old) version.