# Yocto Project Boost library : Change default package version used in bitbake recipe

Tags: boost, embedded-linux, yocto, recipe

I am developing a **Linux image** operating system using **Yocto Project**.

I am using **SUMO** branch (**Yocto Project 2.5**).

In order to install the **boost library** in my Linux image, I added this line to the **local.conf** file :

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " boost"
```

But I discover that the default version installed is **Boost 1.66.0**.

Under *meta/recipes-support/boost* directory I can find three files :

- recipes-support/boost/boost_1.66.0.bb
- recipes-support/boost/boost-1.66.0.inc
- recipes-support/boost/boost.inc

I think that those are the recipes for this library.

I need to use **version 1.70.0** because I have an application coded using this version.

I don't know how to modify these recipes in order to have the desired version, or is there another method to use ? I don't find any helpful tips on the internet. Can you help me please ?

Thank you!

Comment: Quick and a bit dirty is to rename these files with the other version string. Rerun bitbake, and will fail because the md5sum of the fetched ile is different. But it will tell you the new hashes. Just added these into the file.  See SRC_URI[md5sum] and SRC_URI[sha256sum] in the .inc file.

Comment: @vermaete So as I think I understand from you, I must replace `SRC_URI[md5sum]` , `SRC_URI[sha256sum]` and `SRC_URI` contained in `boost-1.66.0.inc` file with the specific informations of the new boost version and re-run bitbake ?

Comment: The idea of Yocto that you construct your own distribution with help of *layers*. So, you take something as a base and then add another layer(s) if needed.

Comment: @0andriy I don't have a big idea how to construct my own layer and what should I put inside this new layer directory and how I make it functional, I wish I could have a response to my boost question with your method. Otherwise, I must take a quick solution for now.

Comment: @vermaete After replacing md5sum and sha256sum and the source of the required boost, I have errors related to the patch

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [openembedded layer index](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=boost). There you'll find the recipe for boost 1.72. If this recipe doesn't depend on any other components of your system (like gcc version), you'll be able to add this recipe in [your own layer](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#understanding-and-creating-layers). Then, in your `build/local.conf`, after `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "<YOUR_OTHER_PGS> boost"` set the preferred version for boost by adding `PREFERED_VERSION_boost="1.72.0"` to the file and rerun bitbake.

I hope this helps.

Comment: but I mentioned that I need to use `boost 1.70.0` version and not `1.72.0`

Comment: If you can't upgrade your application's dev toolchain to 1.72, then you have to adopt the recipe to build version 1.70.

Comment: How can I adopt the recipe to build version 1.70 ?

Comment: Provided the build process does not change in between those versions, you'll need to change the version in the file/folder names and fix the checksums as mentioned by vermaete in the comment section of your original question. I'll probably also need to patch the patches provided by the original recipe. If you're unlucky you also need to modify the build steps specific for your platform. I'm afraid writing your own recipe is not that trivial. My suggestion would be to update everything to an already existing recipe.

Comment: You are right, because I have already changed the names of files found in the boot directory with the version desired to have, and fixed the checksums. I did not change the patches but when I run bitbake it gives me errors related to patches. I don't know how to fix these errors. Besides, I can't find already existing 1.70 version recipe.